# Upgrading to XE5 from Delphi 5: UDPClient.SendBuffer

Tags: delphi, indy, udpclient

I am upgrading an older version of Delphi to XE5, The older version uses Indy Component UDPClient, XE5 says SendBuffer cannot be called with these arguments.  Will someone please help me.  Here is sample code snippet:

```
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := bpt;
  if i <> 0
  begin 
   //send Reset byte
   myBuff[i] := chr(_reset);      // reboot the LIA
   inc(i);
   IdUDPClient1.SendBuffer(myBuff,i);
  end;
end;
```

where myBuff    : array[0..255] of char;

Thank you in advance for your help.

Mike

Comment: Do you appreciate that `Char` is now a totally different type?

Comment: Call it like `IdUDPClient1.SendBuffer(ToBytes(DataThatYouWantToSend));`.

Comment: @TLama I perceive the problem to be the data that is sent more than how to send it

Comment: @TLama: `ToBytes()` does not have an overload for character arrays. Passing a `char[]` array will invoke the `String` overload, so you would have to make sure the array is null terminated. Otherwise, use `RawToBytes()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your data to a `TIdBytes`, which is a dynamic array of bytes.  You also have to take into account that `Char` is now 2 bytes in size, so if you need to remain compatible with an existing app, use `AnsiChar` or `Byte` instead of `Char`:

```
var
  myBuff: array[0..255] of Byte;
...
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := bpt;
  if i <> 0 then
  begin 
   //send Reset byte
   myBuff[i] := _reset;      // reboot the LIA
   inc(i);
   IdUDPClient1.SendBuffer(RawToBytes(myBuff[0],I));
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
var
  myBuff: TIdBytes;
...
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(myBuff, 256);
  ...
  i := bpt;
  if i <> 0 then
  begin 
   //send Reset byte
   myBuff[i] := _reset;      // reboot the LIA
   inc(i);
   IdUDPClient1.SendBuffer(myBuff);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Remy,  Thank you that did the trick.  Of course now I got a new one with ReceiveBuffer.  I'll try to get it figured out before posting, unless you know what it is: IdUDPClient.ReceiveBuffer(r_buf, buff_Len, -1)

Comment: You have to use a `TIdBytes` for that as well. Use `SetLength()` to pre-allocate it to the desired size, then call `ReceiveBuffer()` with it, and then you can copy out data from it as needed, either directly or with `BytesToRaw()`.

Comment: Tried..No luck.  Starting new thread :(  Thank you so much for your help.  I really do appreciate it!