# Delphi, Indy TIdUDPServer and reading from a TIdUDPClient

Tags: delphi, server, udp, client, indy

**Hello dear community.**

I have :

App A; is my App, with a UDP client and server on same port.
App B; which is out of my control: it is XPlane 11.50 by Laminar Research (it works perfectly, verified with WireShark and other tools for this porpouse) .

Let's pretend following this timeline:

0 App A starts listening port 49000 with IdUDPServer.
1 App A asks (sends a buffer) to App B to ask to send data (IdUDPCLient port 49000) and closes itself;
2 App B starts sending its data until App A stops it like at time 1. (But nothing is coming to my UDP server port, Wireshark  detects data !!!).
3 App A closes IdUTPServer and IUdpClient.

After wasting hundreds lines of code trying, I finally realized that the problem is in the need of reuse immediately the client socket to listen to from XPlane. So all communications must be done via the UDP Client.

I am using Delphi 10.3

Now there are two  problems

1. TIdUDPClient doNOT have s.t. like onread/onreceiver event;
2. there are two ways to read from the UDP client: ReceiveBuffer()/ReceiveString()
   Since the receiving data is an array of Bytes (therefore also ASCII <32) string is not the best way, **BUT** if I used ReceiveBuffer and error would raise and saying "Socket Error #  10040 Message Too Long".

Q. are
How can I get a buffer without errors?
Is there a way to implement an event in UDPCLient triggered when data is in ?

Thank you for relief from this headache ...

here is such small source that raises error

```
Var Loc_Array,Loc_Back_Array:TIdBytes;
    i:integer;
    s:string
begin
   if not Indi_Client.Active then begin
     Show_FeedBack(LB_CLIENT_FEEDBACK, 'Can not send ... Client Disables ');
     Exit;
   end;
   try
     if (Sender=XP_STOP)  then Loc_Array := [ 82, 80, 79, 83, 0, 48, 0 ];
     if (Sender=XP_START) then Loc_Array := [ 82, 80, 79, 83, 0, 49, 0 ];
     if Indi_Client.Active then begin
       Indi_Client.SendBuffer( Loc_Array);
       Show_FeedBack(LB_CLIENT_FEEDBACK,'Send '+Bytes_Values(Loc_Array)+'->' +BytesToString(Loc_Array));
       //
       // here raise the error 10040
       //
       Indi_Client.ReceiveBuffer(Loc_Back_Array);
       //
       s:=Indi_Client.ReceiveString();
     end;
   finally
     if Indi_Client.Active
        then LBL_CLIENT_FEEDBACK.Caption:='Active '+DateTimeToStr(Now)
        else LBL_CLIENT_FEEDBACK.Caption:='Paused ...';
   end;
end;
```

**Here the newest and cleanest code I wrote to try it, accordingly Remis suggestions (as far as I have understood)
XPlane receives a trigger to start and he then sends back both on port 49000 continuously data from same IP the request come from.
Easy. But doesn't work.**

[![XPlane's feedback after sending 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5zTH.png)

```
type
  TMain_Form = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    BTN_START: TButton;
    Indi_Server: TIdUDPServer;
    BTN_STOP: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Indi_ServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
    procedure BTN_STARTClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Main_Form: TMain_Form;
  Receiving,
  XPlane_Start_Sending,
  XPlane_Stop_Sending: TIdBytes;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMain_Form.BTN_STARTClick(Sender: TObject);
Const IP_Dest_1:string = '192.168.1.64';
      IP_Dest_2:string = '127.0.0.1';
begin
     if Indi_Server.Active then begin
       Beep; // a debug bell
       Indi_Server.Active:=False;
     end;
     // You can send this as many as you want
     if (Sender=BTN_START) then begin
       Indi_Server.SendBuffer( IP_Dest_1, 49010, Id_IPv4, XPlane_Start_Sending );
     //Indi_Server.SendBuffer( IP_Dest_2, 49010, Id_IPv4, XPlane_Start_Sending );
     end;
     if (Sender=BTN_STOP) then begin
       Indi_Server.SendBuffer( IP_Dest_1, 49010, Id_IPv4, XPlane_Stop_Sending );
     //Indi_Server.SendBuffer( IP_Dest_2, 49010, Id_IPv4, XPlane_Stop_Sending );
     end;
end;

procedure TMain_Form.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
     XPlane_Stop_Sending  := [ 82, 80, 79, 83, 0, 48,  0]; // 0 stop sending (zero item per second)
     XPlane_Start_Sending := [ 82, 80, 79, 83, 0, 49, 48,  0]; // 10 items per second
     //
     with Indi_Server do begin // as dropper onto the form from the palette
       DefaultPort:=49000;
       ReuseSocket:=TIdReuseSocket.rsTrue;
     end;
end;

procedure TMain_Form.Indi_ServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var i:Integer;
    s:string;
begin
     ListBox1.Items.Clear;
     Receiving:=AData;
     ListBox1.Items.Add( BytesToString(Receiving) );
     ListBox1.Items.Add( BytesToString(AData) );
     for i:=Low(Receiving) to High(Receiving) do begin
       s:=s+Receiving[i].ToString+'  ';
     end;
     ListBox1.Items.Add(s);
     ListBox1.Items.Add('-------------------------');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137987/800214) help you?

Comment: Just an FYI, you do not need to use `TIdUDPClient` and `TIdUDPServer` at the same time. You can send outbound packets with `TIdUDPServer`, just send out using the same `Binding` that you are listening on, then your app can act as both client and server at the same time without having to use `TIdUDPClient` at all, and so you won't have any issue with port reuse.

Comment: I think the reason for "Socket Error # 10040 Message Too Long" is that you don't set the length of the `Loc_Back_Array` to something sufficient to hold the data you expect to receive.

Comment: Thank you Remy, but it does not work. XPlane can not ear UDP server.
this is the code:
  object Indi_Server: TIdUDPServer
    Bindings = <
      item
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
        Port = 49000
      end
      item
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
        Port = 49001
      end>
    DefaultPort = 0
    ReuseSocket = rsTrue
    OnUDPRead = Indi_ServerUDPRead
    Left = 664
    Top = 128
  end

and then 

     Indi_Server.SendBuffer( '127.0.0.1', 49000, Id_IPv4, Loc_Array);
     Indi_Server.SendBuffer( '127.0.0.1', 49001, Id_IPv4, Loc_Array);

 But nothing is received by XPlane

Comment: Hi Tom. Loc_Back_Array if TIdBytes so dynamic/open array. 
There must be other kind of error in Indy, i think.

Comment: `Loc_Back_Array` is dynamic. Its size can change only by assigning a value to it (like you do to `Loc_Array`) or by passing it to `SetLength()`. I have confirmed  with a simple test including `TIdUDPClient` that the error you see is due to not setting the length of `Loc_Back_Array`.

Comment: @GiovanniBrambilla For `TIdUDPClient.ReceiveBuffer()`, you need to pre-allocate the length of the `TIdBytes` to a size that handles the largest possible message you will receive, to avoid truncating data. `ReceiveBuffer()` will simply read data into that existing memory, it does not adjust the `TIdBytes` for you. `TIdUDPServer`, on the other hand, has a `BufferSize` property which is set to 8KB by default, set that to whatever size you really need. `TIdUDPServer` will create, pre-size, and adjust an internal `TIdBytes` for each packet received and passed to the `OnUDPRead` event.

Comment: @GiovanniBrambilla as for the XPlane issue, you are sending your data to `TIdUDPServer`, not to the XPlane. You are binding the `TIdUDPServer` to listen on BOTH `127.0.0.1:49000` and `127.0.0.1:49001` (why?), and then you are sending out data FROM `127.0.0.1:49000` TO both `127.0.0.1:49000` and `127.0.0.1:49001`. You need to instead send out to the XPlane's listening IP/Port. If one of those bindings actually belongs to the XPlane, then you should NOT be binding the `TIdUDPServer` to it.

Comment: Thank you Mr Remy and Mr. Tom.
Loc_Back_Array has now same length of buffersize. 

I have added some extra code to show what I have understood, but still XPlane not receiving nor sending data back. XPlane listining port is the same he sends data back.

```